# Is there a GitHub client for Linux?

Tags: linux, software-development, github

Is there a GitHub client for Linux?

Please note that I'm not looking for a **git** client for Linux. (But it doesn't matter whether it is built by GitHub, or by a third party using GitHub's API.)

The reason that a GitHub client is sometimes desirable is that otherwise you need to break your workflow when performing a GitHub specific action, such as making a Pull Request.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Why won't any normal git client work? We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/155) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

Comment: @DanteTheEgregore clarified question.

Comment: Could you please make a list of the Github-specific features you want? For instance pull request, issue tracking, etc. By the way, can one create/merge pull requests using the official Github Mac/Windows client?

Comment: @EricWilson: Pull Requests are not specific for GitHub. They are a part of git.

Comment: @moose I didn't realize that. What is the git command for creating a Pull Request?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630774/how-to-make-pull-requests-without-a-github-account

Comment: @moose Interesting, but seems clear from the comments there that this won't create a GitHub pull request.

Comment: Github does have its own non-standard implementation of Git pull requests, which is one reason why [Linus Torvalds doesn't accept pull requests on Github](http://www.wired.com/2012/05/torvalds_github/).

Answer (score 4):

There is no dedicated official Github client for Linux at this time.

There are, however, several GUI Git clients that will work with Github. I know you say you're not looking for Git clients, so if you're fully committed to that stance your answer is in the first sentence of this post. However, it's important to note that Github *is* Git, just a hosted version of it with some minor tweaks. You can use any Git client to interact with it, and there are many GUI clients that give a similar polish and ease of use to the process as you would expect from the official client.

There are [many options](http://git-scm.com/downloads/guis), but of them all I recommend [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/) for having a good user experience and good Github-specific integration (supporting Github-style pull requests and comments). It's the one I use for Linux when not using the command line. The diff/merge view is really nice.

You may also prefer [GitEye](http://www.collab.net/giteyeapp#tab1) if your focus is more on integrating GitHub's issue tracking. However, that's the extent of their GitHub-specific support.

Comment: GitHub is a bit more than git, I've tried to illustrate the difference in my edit to the question.

Comment: I am not sure you understood my answer then. I think you heard me saying "I'm not telling you exactly what you want to hear" and understood it as "I'm telling you nothing you'll want to hear.  "The client I suggested *does* support Github pull requests via the GitHub API. Please review the information on this page under "Manage Pull Requests": http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/github. You may also appreciate the quote on that page: "Just purchased SmartGit. Absolutely fantastic github tool. Heads and shoulders better than any other I have used. John Papa"

Comment: I understood you, just quibbling with you "GitHub _is_ git" statement.

Comment: The statement's meaning was not that they are identical, but that they are far from mutually exclusive. Any client that supports Github will implicitly have to support git. Even the Github official clients are still technically git clients. Your post gave the impression that you might not be aware of this, hence my statement that "Github *is* git". Apparently we are both quibbling over finer points neither of us was actually missing. :)  If you see room for further improvement to my answer, please let me know. I do think SmartGit is the best option available at present.

Answer (score 2):

Have you heard about [hub](https://github.com/github/hub#commands)?

It augments git with some very handy [github related commands](https://github.com/github/hub#commands):

> Assuming you've aliased hub as `git`, the following commands now have
>   superpowers:
>
> #### git clone
>
> ```
> $ git clone schacon/ticgit
> > git clone git://github.com/schacon/ticgit.git
>
> $ git clone -p schacon/ticgit
> > git clone git@github.com:schacon/ticgit.git
>
> $ git clone resque
> > git clone git@github.com/YOUR_USER/resque.git
> ```
>
> #### git fork
>
> ```
> $ git fork
> [ repo forked on GitHub ]
> > git remote add -f YOUR_USER git@github.com:YOUR_USER/CURRENT_REPO.git
> ```
>
> #### git pull-request
>
> ```
> # while on a topic branch called "feature":
> $ git pull-request
> [ opens text editor to edit title & body for the request ]
> [ opened pull request on GitHub for "YOUR_USER:feature" ]
>
> # explicit title, pull base & head:
> $ git pull-request -m "Implemented feature X" -b defunkt:master -h mislav:feature
> ```
>
> #### git create
>
> ```
> $ git create
> [ repo created on GitHub ]
> > git remote add origin git@github.com:YOUR_USER/CURRENT_REPO.git
>
> # with description:
> $ git create -d 'It shall be mine, all mine!'
>
> $ git create recipes
> [ repo created on GitHub ]
> > git remote add origin git@github.com:YOUR_USER/recipes.git
>
> $ git create sinatra/recipes
> [ repo created in GitHub organization ]
> > git remote add origin git@github.com:sinatra/recipes.git
> ```

And some more.

When a GUI is not a must, it can be a handy tool.